# Select from data.frame based on another data.frame in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a very simple question I struggling to solve in R (find many answers in other coding systems).

I have a `data.frame` with an ID field with several IDs:

```
> data_new <- data.frame(ID_ornitho = c("1344", "2364", "1111","2254"))
> data_new
  ID_ornitho
1       1344
2       2364
3       1111
4       2254
```

I have another `data.frame` with ID's already used:

```
> data_old <- data.frame(ID_ornitho = c("2354", "2364", "2254","1354"))
> data_old
  ID_ornitho
1       2354
2       2364
3       2254
4       1354
```

What I would like to do is simple to delete from `data_new` the rows corresponding to ID's already used in `data_old`, achieving this:

```
> data_filtered
  ID_ornitho
1       1344
2       1111
```

So simple that I cannot find a simple way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect usecase for `anti_join` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by="ID_ornitho")
```

```
  ID_ornitho
1       1344
3       1111
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to filter for existing ids:

```
library(dplyr)
data_old <- data.frame(ID_ornitho = c("2354", "2364", "2254","1354"))
data_new <- data.frame(ID_ornitho = c("1344", "2364", "1111","2254"))
data_new %>% filter(!(ID_ornitho %in% data_old$ID_ornitho))
```

This gives

```
data_new %>% filter(!(ID_ornitho %in% data_old$ID_ornitho))
  ID_ornitho
1       1344
2       1111
```

Answer (score 1):

Staying in base, you can use a logical vector to subset `data_new` like so:

```
data.frame(ID_ornitho=
               data_new[!data_new$ID_ornitho %in% data_old$ID_ornitho, ])
```

See `? match` for details and more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use library(dplyr)

```
anti_join(x,y by="ID_ornitho", copy= False)
```